# How can I tell what version I am running with cleos version client?

Tags: cleos, eosio.cdt

`cleos version client` returns a foreign language to me.

```
Build version: 59626f1e
```

Is there a way I can ascertain what version I'm on from that?  Is there another way of doing it besides that?

Comment: Luckily now it gives an actual version number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cleos version client` does returned the version. However, it is the build version.

To translate into human readable version, you can check https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tags and search for the build version.
Then you can find the version as `v1.4.4`.

The `59626f1e` you got is the first 8 digit hash of the last git commit used to build cleos. Which can be considered as id of that commit. The code can be found at https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/59626f1e .